# CSS select element with class, only if it is NOT first child of parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a *div.container* that has lots of *p* elements inside it. Few of them has class *p.special*. I need to select *p.special* elements, but ONLY if they are NOT at the very top of the parent element (not first child element of parent *.container*).

P.S. I know this can be done easily with jQuery, but I'd prefere plain CSS solution for this.

Here I made explaining sample picture to make myself clear:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `:not` and `:first-child` selectors should do it.

```
.special:not(:first-child) {}
```

Comment: As funny as it may sound, I can swear that I tried this as the very first approach, and it didn't worked for me then, but it does now, when I tried for a second time. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Artanis no problemo.